# Deserialize datamember multiple names

Tags: .net, json, serialization

I have this filed named 1_method

```
public class DerivedClass
{

    [DataMember(Name="1_method")]
    public virtual string FirstMethod { get; protected set; }

}
```

When I Deserialize json, I need that it can map to various names.
How can I achieve something like the following pseudo-code?

```
public class DerivedClass
{

    [DataMember(Name="1_method",Name="2_method")]
    public virtual string FirstMethod { get; protected set; }

}
```

Or like this:

```
public class DerivedClass
{

    [DataMember(Name="1_method")]
   [DataMember(Name="2_method")]
    public virtual string FirstMethod { get; protected set; }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

as far as i have worked out, you cant have multiple names for datamember attributes, you just have to use the same internal variable for storage.

```
public class DerivedClass
{
   string _internal;
   [DataMember(Name="1_method")]
   public virtual string FirstMethod { 
        get{
         return this._internal;
        }
        protected set {
         this._internal = value;
        }
   }

 [DataMember(Name="2_method")]
 public virtual string SecondMethod { 
        get{
         return this._internal;
        }
        protected set {
         this._internal = value;
        }
 }
}
```