# How to accept multiple names for a single property on newtonsoft JSON de-serialization?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

We have a standard `json` format that we defined (the typo is on purpose):

```
{
  "Name" : "John",
  "Salari" : "150000"
}
```

which is de-serialized (using newtonsoft) to:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public string Salari;
}
```

Is there a way to change `Salari` to `Salary` and still be able to accept messages with the old name?
Something like:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name;
    [DeserializeAlso("Salari")]
    public string Salary;
}
```

To make newtonsoft de-serializer understand that `Salari` should be de-serialized to the `Salary` field?

Comment: Is string.Replace("\"Salari\",\"Salary\") is out of the question?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860602/json-net-jsonserializer-attribute-for-custom-naming) out.

Comment: @Nissim I'd rather not since that would require keeping track of it in a lot of places

Comment: @AndreiV Wouldn't that cross 'Salary' off and just keep 'Salari' ?

Comment: @AndreiV I think shmoopy wants to use anonymous objects. the answer you referenced requires the object to exist

Comment: I think I understand now: you want `{"Name" : "John",  "Salari" : "150000"}` and `{"Name" : "John",  "Salary" : "150000"}` to be deserialized in the same way, i.e. in the same object type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366523/deserialize-datamember-multiple-names

Comment: I don't think that that's possible out of the box... You might need a custom deserializer.

Comment: @BojanKomazec Thanks! it's getting impossible now days to ask a unique question in SO :)

Comment: Create a custom converter that accepts both spellings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of properties:

```
class Person
{
  protected string _Salary;
  public string Salary
  {
    get { return _Salary; }
    set { _Salary = value; }
  }
  public string Name { get; set; } 
}

class BackwardCompatiblePerson : Person
{
  public string Salari 
  {
    get { return _Salary; }
    set { _Salary = value; }
  }
}
```

And use `Person` for serialization & `BackwardCompatiblePerson` for deserialization.